# My Macbook Air won't connect to the internet

Tags: wifi, macbook-pro, internet

I have a Macbook Air I bought in November 2011, v 10.7.4 and I have issues connecting to the internet. Though the wifi symbol shows that I have a strong connection, I have no internet access. The only way to get it is to shut down my laptop, and reset my router by turning the power off and waiting for a bit then turning it back on. I know I don't have a problem with my router/internet access as other users in my flat have no trouble. Anyone have any idea what the trouble is?

Comment: Hi, I have a number of questions. 

1. Did you ever have a wifi connection? If so, has something changed?

2. If you connect your computer through Ethernet, does that work?

3. If you take you computer to a Starbucks or equivalent, do you get wifi access?

4. Can you update your question with a screenshot of your internet connections?

Answer (score 2):

Things to check:

1. If you are using WIFI only, you need to set the Service Order and the first will be your WIFI.

From System Preferences > Network

[image]

Then Click "Set Service Order"

Drag and drop the WIFI connection to the top of the order list

[image]

2. On your Network Settings > Wifi > Advanced > DNS, add your Router IP there.

HTH